# How can I make the app open in the second activity for a certain amount of time?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer

I have an app that takes user input and displays it in the second activity, I am saving the user input via savedPreferences. But if I exit the app, it goes back to the main activity. How could I open the second activity, when the user reopens the app, for a certain amount of time (24hrs)? And then go back to start activity after that time period?

Reference code would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you will need a `CountDownTimer`, override `OnStop` to save the current stated of the timer in a `SharedPreference` and when you open you app check for the value of the `SharedPreference` variable that you stored if it is not zero the the timer was not complete, open `SecondActivity` and continue the countDown timer with the Store value.

```
private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
        }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);

    editor.apply();

    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);

    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime;

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis <= 0) {
            
          } else {
           startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        }
    }
}
```

the code is a bit rusty and in java but that is how you can go about it